# How to keep XML in URLs from being interpreted?

Tags: php, xml, echo

I'm trying to get PHP to echo this:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=<TrackRequest USERID=\"123456\"><TrackID ID=".$trackno."></TrackID></TrackRequest>";
```

However, when I open this page in my browser (FF4), only this shows up:

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=
```

The browser thinks that  onwards is part of a XML document so it does not render it, as shown here:

[image]

(parts blanked out for obvious reasons :D)

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: run `htmlentities()` on the string before outputing it.  The browser is interpreting `<TrackRequest` as a tag.  It'll only display the way you want it to as `&lt;TrackRequest` etc.

Comment: It's not a problem with `echo` then, is it? :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$a = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=<TrackRequest USERID=\"123456\"><TrackID ID=".$trackno."></TrackID></TrackRequest>";
echo htmlentities($a);
```

or

```
echo "<pre>$a</pre>"; // the first is better;
```

Answer (score 2):

It will parse it as HTML. It has nothing to do with XML. Use the Content-Type text/plain [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to tell the browser it is plain text.

If this url is not the only output, but it is part of a HTML page, use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)  or [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: How do I use the htmlentitles and htmlspecialchars function? I tried doing htmlentitles($url) and htmlspecialchars($url) but still the same result... thanks!